# How do I JOIN multiple tables where some, not all, columns are the same and return the sum of each column?

Tags: php, mysql, outer-join

I have multiple tables that track information from different locations (i.e. cold vs. warm) that provide service depending on the seasons and need to create a corporate level view of the locations.

Looking at the descriptions for UNIONS and JOINS, it looks like the tables have to have either the same number of columns or the same column name. What I need is a result providing the sum of the columns that are the same and the sum of the columns that are unique using PHP MySQL.

```html
Table1
+-------+-------+-------+
| col-A | col-B | col-C |
+-------+-------+-------+
|   2   |    8  |   5   |
+-------+-------+-------+
|   1   |    9  |   7   |
+-------+-------+-------+
|   3   |    2  |   3   |
+-------+-------+-------+

Table2
+-------+-------+-------+
| col-1 | col-2 | col-3 |
+-------+-------+-------+
|   2   |    1  |   6   |
+-------+-------+-------+
|   5   |    5  |   4   |
+-------+-------+-------+
|   2   |    7  |   3   |
+-------+-------+-------+

Table3
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| col-A | col-B | col-1 | col-2 | col-3 | col-4 |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|   9   |    4  |   1   |   2   |    1  |   4   |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|   2   |    6  |   6   |   8   |    3  |   6   |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|   4   |    7  |   3   |   2   |    4  |   5   |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+

Result Table
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| col-A | col-B | col-C | col-1 | col-2 | col-3 | col-4 |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|   21  |   36  |   15  |   19  |   25  |   21  |   15  |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this can be done with `UNION` like below:

```
SELECT SUM(`col-A`) AS 'Col-A',SUM(`col-b`) AS 'Col-B',
       SUM(`col-C`) AS 'Col-C',SUM(`col-1`) AS 'Col-1',
       SUM(`col-2`) AS 'Col-2',SUM(`col-3`) AS 'Col-3',SUM(`col-4`) AS 'Col-4' 
  FROM
(SELECT `col-A`,`col-b`,0 AS 'col-c',`col-1`,`col-2`,`col-3`,`col-4` FROM table_3 UNION
SELECT 0,0,0,`col-1`,`col-2`,`col-3`,0 FROM table_2 UNION
SELECT `col-A`,`col-b`,`col-C`, 0,0,0,0 FROM table_1 ) XX
```

Because table_3 has the most columns, I put it on top of the union. The following queries only need to fill `0`(zero) where the column not exists in the table to fulfill the union requirement.

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick and I think I understand the concept now. Use "0" for columns that are "missing". Now I just need to figure out how to accomplish this solution for a dynamic database (weather is unpredictable).

Comment: Question: why do I have to include the "xx" at the end. I tried the solution without it and received errors.

Comment: The XX works as an alias for the sub-query. It's like assigning the sub-query to a name and it treats as table names. You can change to any varchar value you want like `A, B, A1, B1, mytable, subtable` etc.